# Why does a user have to enter "Profile" data to enter data into other tables?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

**EDIT**
**It appears the user has to enter some data for his profile, otherwise I get this error below. I guess if there is no profile data, the user can not continue to enter data in other tables by default? I do not want to make entering user profile data a requirement to use the rest of the sites functionality, how can I get around this?**

**EDIT 2**
**OK I will try: [To DROP a FOREIGN KEY Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)** However, my table doesn't have a foreign key column....?

(Notes- [Ref1](http://forums.asp.net/p/1616135/4144230.aspx), [Ref2](http://forums.asp.net/p/1393074/2983784.aspx#2983784?FOREIGN+KEY))

**Original Question:**

---

Currently I have been testing everything with the same user and everything has been working fine.

However, when I created a new user for the very first time and tried to **enter data** into my custom table, I get the following error.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with
>   the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_UserData_aspnet_Profile". The
>   conflict occurred in database
>   "C:\ISTATE\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF",
>   table "dbo.aspnet_Profile", column
>   'UserId'. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Not sure why I am getting this error. I have the user controls set up in ASP.NET 3.5 however all I am using is my own table or at least that I am aware of.

I have a custom `UserData` table that includes the columns:

```
id, UserProfileID, CL, LL, SL, DateTime
```

(id is the auto incremented int) The intent is that all users will add their data in this table and as I mentioned above it has been working fine for my original first user I created. However, when i created a new user I am getting this problem.

Here is the code that updates the database.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //connect to database
        MySqlConnection database = new MySqlConnection();
        database.CreateConn(); 

        //create command object
        Command = new SqlCommand(queryString, database.Connection);

        //add parameters. used to prevent sql injection
        Command.Parameters.Add("@UID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
        Command.Parameters["@UID"].Value = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

        Command.Parameters.Add("@CL", SqlDbType.Int);
        Command.Parameters["@CL"].Value = InCL.Text;

        Command.Parameters.Add("@LL", SqlDbType.Int);
        Command.Parameters["@LL"].Value = InLL.Text;

        Command.Parameters.Add("@SL", SqlDbType.Int);
        Command.Parameters["@SL"].Value = InSL.Text;

        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
```

Source Error:

> Line 84:
>   Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a foreign key constraint between the UserData and Profile tables. When there is not a record in asp_Profile that has a UserID value that equals UserProfileID in your new record in UserData table, you get this error. Not sure what your goal is, but sounds like you should just delete the FK_UserData_aspnet_Profile constraint, and then make UserData.UserProfileID nullable, since there will not always be a record in profile corresponding with your UserData table.

Comment: Any clue how to get rid of the FK_UserData_aspnet_Profile constraint?

Comment: I assume you're using MS SQL Server? In Management Studio, drill down to the table. Open the Constraints folder beneath the table, right-click on FK_UserData_aspnet_Profile, and select delete.

Answer (score 1):

Make UserProfileID nullable and pass DBNull to UID parameter if the user didn't enter the data.

Comment: Davita, I think I understand the second part but how does making "UserProfileID" nullable help this? For the data, I will always need to have the "UserProfileID" entered whenever data is entered.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the value you're trying to enter into the `UserProfileID` column does not exist in any row of the `Profile` table in the `UserID` column.

Maybe ProviderUserKey isn't what you should use here.

Answer (score 0):

This took care of it -

```
  ALTER TABLE UserData
    DROP CONSTRAINT FK_UserData_aspnet_Profile;
```